# Identify same elements if they don't have different classes

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I was trying to scrape a page `http://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=296-17A&full=true` to get an output of type

```
'6903-03' : u'Aerial spraying, seeding, crop dusting, or firefighting' ,
'6510-00' : u'Domestic servants/home care assistants employed in or about the private residence
of a home owner' ,
'1407-00' : u'Bus companies' ,
```

I am using scrapy for the same. I used the following xpath for it

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlSectionContent"]/span/div/span/text()').extract())
```

Even though it works properly but it returns some not required lines as well like these

```
u'which also provide farm kill operations away from the custom meat shop',
u'Farm kill operations',
u'only',
u'no farm kill',
u'only',
u'4302-16 Farm kill',
u'exclusively',
u'only; ',
u'only',
u'no farm kill',
u'including farm kill',
```

One way I was trying to think was to do a regex on each line to identify the pattern line with regex as `u'(?:\d{2}){2}-(?:\d{1}){2} [A-Za-z ]*'`

Is there any better or cleaner approach of identifying such spans.

PS:- The spans don't have any classes. They have only style. I am not sure if I can use styles for identifying the required spans.

Comment: ie. `xpath("//span[@style="font-weight:bold;text-indent:0in;"]/text()")` - but page may need more complex xpath.

Comment: You should add 2-3 html examples of the different elements.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath might be more specific and include h3 tags to be able to reference its next sibling

```
'//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlSectionContent"]/descendant::h3/following-sibling::div[1]/span/text()'
```

can be tested in Linux/Cygwin with

```
xmllint --recover --html --xpath '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlSectionContent"]/descendant::h3/following-sibling::div[1]/span' ~/tmp/test.html| sed -re 's%<span style=[^>]+>([^<]+)</span>%\1\n%g' | less
```

sample output

```
0101-00 Land clearing: Highway, street and road construction, N.O.C.
0103-09 Drilling or blasting: N.O.C.
0104-12 Dredging, N.O.C.
```